# Getting an issue writing an apache camel test

Tags: java, junit, apache-camel

Am writing a test case for for an apache camel route and am getting this error when running it ( stack is pointing the the advice with part of the code for the error.. )

```
 @Test
    public void testRoute() throws Exception {

        AdviceWith.adviceWith(context, Endpoints.SEDA_SEND_ENDPOINT, a -> {
            a.mockEndpoints(Endpoints.SEDA_SEND_ENDPOINT);
        });
    //     Set up the expectations for the mock endpoint

       getMockEndpoint("mock:" + Endpoints.SEDA_SEND_ENDPOINT).expectedMessageCount(1);

        // Send a message to the seda:sendMessage endpoint
        template.sendBody(Endpoints.SEDA_SEND_ENDPOINT, "test message");

        // Verify that the mock endpoint expectations are met
        assertMockEndpointsSatisfied();
     //   



    }
```

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot advice route as there are no routes
> at org.apache.camel.builder.AdviceWith.findRouteDefinition(AdviceWith.java:262)
> at org.apache.camel.builder.AdviceWith.adviceWith(AdviceWith.java:74)
> at com.sams.pricing.prism.data.processor.CamelRouteTests1.testRoute(CamelRouteTests1.java:26)
> at java.base/

Have thought that perhaps the endpoint is written incorrectly but double checked and even wrote it out, still getting the issue

SEDA_SEND_ENDPOINT = "seda:sendMessage?blockWhenFull=true&concurrentConsumers=100"

Comment: It seems an empty Camel context (with no route at all) is booted when the test in run. How do you kick in Camel in your unit test ?

Comment: Do we need to mock the route in the test-class? Can we not call the route directly from the service class

Answer (score 1):

if You want to test routeContext like below:

```
<camelcontext>
   <routeContext>
       <route id="test">
           <from uri="direct:test"/>
           <to uri="bean:check"/>
       </route>
   </routeContext>
</camelcontext>
```

follow the test case like this :

```
@Test
public void testRoute() throws Exception {
   RouteDefinition route = context.getRouteDefinition("test");
   AdviceWith.adviceWith(route, context, new AdviceWithRouteBuilder() {
       @Override
       public void configure() throws Exception {
           weaveAddLast().to(Endpoints.SEDA_SEND_ENDPOINT);
       }
   });
   
   MockEndpoint mockEndpoint =getMockEndpoint(Endpoints.SEDA_SEND_ENDPOINT).expectedMessageCount(1);
   LeapCoreTestUtils.template.sendBody("direct:test", "test message");
   mockEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied();
}
```